# List and CSV Reader of python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a small CSV file:

```
name,dept,city
sri,cse,hyd
vatsasa,ece,bang
```

I can read the csv file through csvreader as following:

```
response = s3.get_object(Bucket=src_bucket, Key=key)
lines = response['Body'].read().splitlines(True)
reader = csv.reader(lines)
first_row = next(reader)
print(' first row is: ', first_row)
readers=list(reader)
for row1 in readers:
    print('this is second iteration: ', row1)
```

Below is the result of above code:

```
first row is: ['name', 'Dept', 'City']
this is second iteration: ['sree', 'NULL', 'Bengaluru']
this is second iteration: ['vatsasa', 'NULL', 'Hyd']
this is second iteration: ['NULL', 'NULL', 'VJA']
this is second iteration: ['capgemini', 'NULL', 'TPTY']
this is second iteration: ['DTP', 'NULL', 'NULL']
this is second iteration: ['Bengaluru', 'NULL', 'TVM']
this is second iteration: ['sre', 'NULL', 'MNGL']
this is second iteration: ['vatsas', 'NULL', 'Kochi']
this is second iteration: ['NULL', 'NULL', 'TVM']
this is second iteration: ['capgemin', 'NULL', 'MNGL']
this is second iteration: ['DTP9', 'NULL', 'Kochi']
this is second iteration: ['NULL', 'NULL', 'TVM']
this is second iteration: ['sree0', 'NULL', 'MNGL']
```

However, i had tried to print rows from reader at end of the script as:

```
response = s3.get_object(Bucket=src_bucket, Key=key)
lines = response['Body'].read().splitlines(True)
reader = csv.reader(lines)
first_row = next(reader)
print(' first row is: ', first_row)
readers=list(reader)
for row1 in readers:
print('this is second iteration: ', row1)
for row in reader:
    print('this is first iteration: ', row)
```

But result is same as above one:

```
first row is: ['name', 'Dept', 'City']
this is second iteration: ['sree', 'NULL', 'Bengaluru']
this is second iteration: ['vatsasa', 'NULL', 'Hyd']
this is second iteration: ['NULL', 'NULL', 'VJA']
this is second iteration: ['capgemini', 'NULL', 'TPTY']
this is second iteration: ['DTP', 'NULL', 'NULL']
this is second iteration: ['Bengaluru', 'NULL', 'TVM']
this is second iteration: ['sre', 'NULL', 'MNGL']
this is second iteration: ['vatsas', 'NULL', 'Kochi']
this is second iteration: ['NULL', 'NULL', 'TVM']
this is second iteration: ['capgemin', 'NULL', 'MNGL']
this is second iteration: ['DTP9', 'NULL', 'Kochi']
this is second iteration: ['NULL', 'NULL', 'TVM']
this is second iteration: ['sree0', 'NULL', 'MNGL']
```

Rows from first iteration i.e rows from reader are not printed.

My concern is, i have to use my csv file for further checks, but unable to read rows from 'reader' at first.

For for confirmation, is it proper to use 'readers' for further process or need to read from 'reader'?

Note: Tried this code on aws lambda

Comment: `first row is: ` is not present in any of the snippets. Can you check if you have pasted correct code here?

Comment: Apologizes, added print statement for first_row :)

Comment: `reader` iterates through the CSV, and then is done. This statement: `readers=list(reader)` reads the entire CSV file, at which point there is nothing more for reader to read. So trying to read more from it with a for loop does nothing - if you want to look at the contents again, look at the `readers` list that was created.

Comment: @PaulMcG: So can we able to perform operation on that list, as how we do for normal csv file? and at same time, can we write to another csv file by using write.writerows command

Comment: Well, it's a *list*, so you can do any list operations on it you like. Perhaps if you changed the variable name to `rows` as in `rows = list(reader)`, it might be clearer to you. Then your for loop would read `for row1 in rows:, …etc.`. The first row from the CSV would be `rows[0]`, you can get the number of rows using `len(rows)`, and you should indeed be able to use these rows as the argument passed to writerows. Instead of posting more questions/comments asking what you can do, just try these steps for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

there is a bug in your code  in line

```
for row in reader:
    print('this is first iteration: ', row)
```

use **readers** instead of ***reader***